# AngularJS and JSP

Tags: angularjs, jsp, servlets

There is a legacy application built upon JSP, Struts2.0, Ajax, JavaScript and Servlet and there are a lot of JSP pages involved in project. Now we want to put angularJS to gradually replace the JSP pages.

Since it is a huge project and about 200+ pages are already designed in JSP, we have to keep AngularJS and JSP parallely deployed in the application. 
Now how to put the AnugularJS pages in this existing application and what will be the folder structure.

Comment: partial implementation is probably a bad idea. angular is meant for frontend rendering and jsp is for server side rendering. not sure how are your pages gonna communicate.

Comment: I am new to MVC approach. is there any way we can redirect call from angularJS to JSP and vice versa.

Comment: partial implementation will be there in initial stage, later the whole project will converted to angular js approach.